# How to access files mounted by docker-compose's volumes in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Workspace folder structure (=`my_application`):

```
 ➜ tree -L 2
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── configs
│     ├── configure_all.sh
│     ├── create_connections.sh
│     ├── requirements
│     └── variables.json
...
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  my_service:
    build: .
    
    ...
    
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/my_application

  ...
```

Note that whole workspace directory is mounted (it has to) on`/opt/my_application`.

Finally, the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
USER root

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential gcc git wget unzip \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN sh /opt/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh
```

But this raised an error, cuz `/opt/my_application/` is not mounted yet in build time.

I know I can use something like `COPY` command but it makes me build the image every time I change(or fix) any file in the `configs` which is really annoying. I'd like to take advantage of `volumes` of `docker-compose.yml`, which sync the changes continuously.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try  with 
CMD /opt/my_application/configs/configure_all.sh

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this the way you describe.  Volumes intrinsically don't get mounted until after the image is built.  You can run multiple containers off the same image, with potentially different (or no) volumes mounted, and the image doesn't get rebuilt.

> ... build the image every time I change(or fix) any file in the `configs` ...

It might help to think of your application in a couple of different pieces:

1. You have the application itself, which won't change when it gets re-run.
2. You have the `configs` which could be different from run to run.
3. You have any data the application generates while it's running, which can be discarded when it's finished.

You can use a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to inject the configuration, even if the rest of the application is "baked in" to the image.

The first thing I'd recommend doing, then, is updating your Dockerfile to `COPY` in the application code, `RUN` any commands that you need to run to build it, and set the default `CMD` to run the application.  A good first step would be to make this run with the `configs` built into the image.

The one complication with your setup is that part of the injected configuration is a runnable script.  Since this comes from a bind mount, the script won't be available until the container starts.  You can use an entrypoint wrapper script to run this at container startup time: provide a shell script that runs as the image's `ENTRYPOINT`, does whatever initial setup, and then ends with `exec "$@"` to run the image's `CMD`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh

# If the configuration includes an initialization script, run it
if [ -x ./configs/configure_all.sh ]; then
  ./configs/configure_all.sh
fi

# Run the main container CMD
exec "$@"
```

(Since this is a shell script, you can do anything a shell script would have done.  If the script sets environment variables, for example, you can use the `.` built-in to set them in the containing shell; or you can have logic depending on if a variable is set or if a file is present; or...)

In the Dockerfile, leave the `CMD` as you had it before, but add this script as the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```sh
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .           # if a `COPY . .` doesn't already include it
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD the_application                   # same as before
```

Finally, when you launch the application, use a `docker run -v` bind mount to *only* inject the `configs` directory; do not overwrite the main application code with a bind mount.

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./configs:/opt/my_application/configs
```

If you want to check what's going on, a `docker-compose run` to launch an interactive debugging shell will replace the `CMD` but not the `ENTRYPOINT`, which means that the setup wrapper will still run but then launch the interactive shell instead of the main application.

```sh
docker-compose run my_service \
  cat /opt/my_application/etc/output_of_configure_all.sh
# ^^^ runs _after_ the setup in the entrypoint script
#     runs _instead of_ the default container CMD (or Compose command:)
```